# How to turn a one-to-one relationship to one-to-many relationship

Tags: datatable, many-to-many, one-to-many, data-modeling, one-to-one

The relationship between my fact table and dimension table is one-to-one. What can I do to turn the relationship to one-to-many.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1zDi.jpg

[1]:

Comment: What modelling tool are you using? I’m guessing you just select the join and change its properties

Comment: I'm using Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships#edit-a-relationship) explains how to edit a relationship